# How can I upload CRX/NEX extension in opera gallery with certain ID?

Tags: opera-extension

I'd like to upload CRX/NEX extension in opera gallery with certain ID. In Google Chrome gallery I can upload a zipped extension and add "chrome.pem" file in archive. Is there similar solution for opera gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a similar solution for the Opera addons gallery as well. Check out http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/tut_conversion.html for info on this.